# How to know the exact output from a Python subprocess.check_output() call?

Tags: python, bash, exception, error-handling

I'm running some terminal commands from within Python using the [subprocess.check_output() call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). This works all fine when it returns correct results. When interacting with the bitcoin daemon I can get several responses however. For example, the raw output (as seen on a normal bash command line) can be:

```
: Cannot obtain a lock on data directory /home/kramer65/.bitcoin. Bitcoin is probably already running.
```

or

```
error: couldn't connect to server
```

Both these responses give an error code 1 however. I tried printing out the following attributes of the `subprocess.CalledProcessError as e`, which in both cases results in the same outputs (except for the `cmd` attribute of course:

```
print e.args, e.cmd, e.message, e.output, e.returncode
#       ()   'BTC'                            1
#       ()   'BTC getinfo'                    1
```

I guess the only thing that distincts the two errors, is the raw string that is outputted on the command line which I listed above. So my question is: how can I get the raw string that is shown on the command line from within Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely coming on the `stderr`.

You could setup your subprocess with

`stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`

as a kwarg to merge the stdout and stderr together.

Alternatively, if you need them separately, do something like

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

Note: unlike `check_output`, this method will not raise exception if the return code was nonzero, so you will have to do that manually if that's the behaviour you wanted.